# jQuery .mousenter doesn't work after redraw

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery grid that can be redrawn after a button click. This is for an Etch-a-Sketch project for The Odin Project.

The code works the first time and lets the user choose the size of grid and then draw on .mouseenter.  However, when they click the button to reset it no longer allows drawing.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have a jsfiddle for the project at https://jsfiddle.net/davidtaylorjr/cLcbxmnb/14/

HTML:

```
<div class="grid_controls">
   <button class="clear button">Clear and Redraw</button>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid_controls {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.box {
    margin:0;
    border:1px solid lightblue;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
}

.container{
    padding:5px;
}


/*=================
General
=================*/

body {
    background: white;
}

/*=================
Sketchpad Holder
=================*/
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}

.box {
    background: white;
    position: relative;
}


.clear {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.box.black {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){

    //Invoke original function
    drawBoxes();

    //Draw .box divs
    function drawBoxes(){
        var gridWidthInBoxes = prompt("Width of grid in boxes?");
        //Remove boxes and redraw
        $('.box').remove();
        for(var i = 0; i < (gridWidthInBoxes * gridWidthInBoxes) ; i++){
            $(".container").append("<div class='box'></div>");
        }
        //Restyle boxes after they have been drawn
        restyle(gridWidthInBoxes);
    }

    //Style .box divs with appropriate width
    function restyle(numberofBoxes){
        //Set width and height css value for '.box' divs
        $('.box').css('width', (100/numberofBoxes)+'%');
        $('.box').css('height', (100/numberofBoxes)+'%');
    }

    //Button event handler
    $("button").on('click', function(){
        drawBoxes();
    });



    //Hover to draw boxes
    $(".box").mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).addClass('black');
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mouseenter` event will never be triggered when you redraw the box.

you will use `.container` to delegate the event

```
$(".container").on('mouseenter', '.box', function() {
  $(this).addClass('black');
});
```

reference: [`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [event delegation syntax](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) of `.on()`

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".box", function() {
    $(this).addClass('black');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cLcbxmnb/17/)**

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the event is not added to the DOM on redraw.
Put this

```
//Hover to draw boxes
$(".box").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).addClass('black');
});
```

inside drawboxes

```
     function drawBoxes(){
            var gridWidthInBoxes = prompt("Width of grid in boxes?");
            //Remove boxes and redraw
            $('.box').remove();
            for(var i = 0; i < (gridWidthInBoxes * gridWidthInBoxes) ; i++){
                $(".container").append("<div class='box'></div>");
            }
            //Restyle boxes after they have been drawn
            restyle(gridWidthInBoxes);
//here
        $(".box").mouseenter(function() {
          $(this).addClass('black');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will help you.

```js
  $(function() {
    //Invoke original function
    drawBoxes();

    //Draw .box divs
    function drawBoxes() {
      var gridWidthInBoxes = prompt("Width of grid in boxes?");
      //Remove boxes and redraw
      //$('.box').remove();
      $(".container").empty();
      for (var i = 0; i < (gridWidthInBoxes * gridWidthInBoxes); i++) {
        $(".container").append("<div class='box'></div>");
      }
      //Restyle boxes after they have been drawn
      restyle(gridWidthInBoxes);
    }

    //Style .box divs with appropriate width
    function restyle(numberofBoxes) {
      //Set width and height css value for '.box' divs
      $('.box').css('width', (100 / numberofBoxes) + '%');
      $('.box').css('height', (100 / numberofBoxes) + '%');
    }

    //Button event handler
    $("button").on('click', function() {
      drawBoxes();

    });



    //Hover to draw boxes
    $(".container").on('mouseenter', '.box', function() {
      $(this).addClass('black');
    });

  });
```

```css
.grid_controls {
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
.box {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.container {
  padding: 5px;
}
/*=================
General
=================*/

body {
  background: white;
}
/*=================
Sketchpad Holder
=================*/

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
.box {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}
.clear {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.box.black {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="grid_controls">

  <button class="clear button">Clear and Redraw</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
```